# Story about girl who enters a book into a fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading many years ago a story about a young girl who is in a very old, very large house or something, and she finds this old book and she gets sucked into it into a fantasy land.  Beyond those details I can't remember much else though.  I know it sounds a lot like the Neverending Story, but that's not it.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Please try to add any other details you can think of. As it stands, it is very broad, and may get closed.

Comment: Since this question has so few details, it's practically unanswerable as there are many books which might satisfy your criteria. Please [edit] to add more description of the book (when did you read it? how old was it? what language was it in? where was it set? what else happened in the story once she'd reached the fantasy land? anything about what the fantasy land was like?) and your question can be reopened. You might also like to read [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking good story-ID questions.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [*Coraline*, by Neil Gaiman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coraline)?

> … a story about a young girl who is in a very old, very large house
>   or something, …

Coraline Jones and her parents move into an old mansion …

> … and she finds this old book and she gets sucked into it into a fantasy land.

Not exactly:

> One rainy day Coraline discovers a locked door ….
>   … Coraline decides to unlock the door ….
>   … a long hallway that leads to a flat identical to her own
>   but inhabited by the “Other Mother” and “Other Father”. 
>   They seem to look like her parents,
>   except that in place of eyes, they have shiny black buttons. 
>   …

Answer (score 2):

Another story with a girl entering the world of a book is *Inkspell*, the second volume of the  [Inkheart trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkheart_trilogy) by Cornelia Funke.

Comment: Also Django Wexler's "The Forbidden Library", but that was published in 2014 so it probably doesn't fit the "Many Years Ago" part of the request.